# How to modify rendering of jQuery Cycle plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I have a mockup design that I think I want to use jQuery Cycle for. The mockup screenshots are below. The closest example of this from jQuery Cycle is this: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager2.html, but it is far from where I want to end up.

How would I modify the jQuery Cycle plugin to get the effect illustrated in the mockups below? I am  ok with going with another jQuery or Javascript plugin that is closer to the mockups if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this Cycle demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html) to start out. It is the basic javascript to get the next/previous buttons working with the cycle plugin. But you will have to do the heavy lifting with CSS to make it look good.

If you don't want to try to make it look good with CSS (meaning fancy buttons and placement of links) you can use one of these two slider plugins:

- http://nivo.dev7studios.com/
- http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/diapo/

The only problem with these plugins, is that you have play by their rules of how your list is set up. I mean you might have a lot more HTML than you actually want on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try bxslider which is closer to your goals :

http://bxslider.com/

e.g :

http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnails-pager-method-1

http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnails-pager-method-2

It's licensed under MIT Licence.